# Is it currently possible to drive from Durrës to Berat in Albania on the SH 4?

Tags: driving, albania, hitchhiking, berat

I'm intending to hitchhike from Durrës to Berat on the SH 4, which looks like the obvious route.

But when I Google Maps for driving directions between these two cities it tells to drive back up to Tiranë first.

Sometimes Google Maps has some glitches in its data but maybe this highway can't be used right now. [Wikipedia mentions that part of it is under construction between Durrës and Rrogozhinë](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_in_Albania#Highway_Sections_Under_Construction) but when I zoom in I can see cars on it.

So it's unclear whether the route can be used but some parts are not up to highway spec or contain detours, or whether I really do have to go back to Tiranë. Does anybody know?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but 2 years ago I was also in the Balkans with my car and I noticed that Google Maps isn't really reliable there for route planning.

Comment: Anywhere east of Europe, Google Maps starts to fall apart. I'd suggest TomTom or OpenStreetMaps.

Comment: Does OpenStreetMaps do route planning now?

Comment: For Georgia Google Maps is one big blank but until now I'd had no problem with it anywhere on my last couple of trips around Central and Eastern Europe, Turkey and beyond. I'll be double checking everything with Tom Tom now though thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used TomTom Route planner to check this out.

And it confirms that [SH4 is their suggested route](http://routes.tomtom.com/route/Durres%252C%2520AL%254041.33083%252C19.4429%2540-1/Berat%252C%2520AL%254040.70749%252C19.97228%2540-1/?leave=now&traffic=true&center=40.959930144641,19.575237499999&zoom=6&map=basic), so I'd suspect it's totally fine to travel on.

Comment: It turned out that Bing Maps suggest the SH4 too and as it was about to get dark I took a punt. The road started off fairly modern at Durrës and then after about Lushnjë got very wobbly indeed but the road was open the whole way so no problem.

Comment: awesome, gotta love the 'taking a punt' options ;)