# Is there a routes site that works properly for the Republic of Georgia?

Tags: online-resources, georgia-country, routes, maps

We do have a question [about alternatives to Google Maps](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/how-to-plan-routes-that-arent-covered-by-google-maps), but it seems to focus on Eastern Europe and even though Georgia is culturally like Europe it's technically in either Western Asia, the Middle East, or the Caucasus, depending on who's opinion you're listening to.

But regardless of what region it's in, it's really hard to find a web site or service that covers it:

- [Tomtom just doesn't work there.](http://routes.tomtom.com/route/Istanbul%252C%2520TR%254041.03749%252C28.98669%2540-1/41.76026%25C2%25B0N%252C%252044.78816%25C2%25B0E%254041.76026%252C44.78816%2540-1/?leave=now&traffic=true&center=41.72696,44.78885&zoom=8&map=basic)
- [Bing Maps also doesn't work there.](http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=41.38283683965212~36.884653091430685&lvl=5&dir=0&sty=r&rtp=pos.41.04085159301758_28.98617935180664_Istanbul,%20Turkey___e_~pos.41.72180938720703_44.78312683105469_Tbilisi,%20Georgia___e_&mode=D&rtop=0~0~0~&form=LMLTCC)
- [Google Maps knows a couple of roads but gives ridiculous advice like "go through Iran and Armenia to get to Tbilisi from Istanbul!](http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&source=s_d&saddr=istanbul&daddr=tbilisi&hl=en&geocode=FdawcQIdQCe6ASlrCGgABKfKFDHQsAG8mP7M4Q;&aq=&sll=41.00527,28.97696&sspn=1.861225,3.532104&vpsrc=0&mra=ls&ie=UTF8&t=h&z=5)

Where else can I look? Maybe there's some site that specializes in an area around Russia or Asia or the Middle East that works better?

Comment: What's the [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) coverage like around where you're interested? If it's quite good, then any one of the number of OSM powered route planners should work for you

Comment: It seems OK but what are these OSM powered route planners of which you speak? I can give them a try and reply.

Comment: I've been looking around for a site that uses OSM and provides routing but I haven't found one that I can get to work with a simplistic `from Istanbul to Tbilisi` yet.

Answer (score 4):

In the comments you said that [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) has good coverage for the areas you're interested in, so I'd suggest you just use one of the many route planners powered by the OSM dataset.

The one I've tended to use is [OpenRouteService](http://www.openrouteservice.org/), which can handle routing by car, bike or foot. I've just tried asking that to route by car from Istanbul to Tbilisi, and it gave me what looked like a perfectly sensible route. [This link](http://www.openrouteservice.org/index.php?start=28.9750523,41.0279801&end=44.7884942,41.7185081&pref=Fastest&lang=en&noMotorways=false&noTollways=false) should hopefully link to the suggested route.

In addition, there's a [full list of route planners](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) on the OpenStreetMap wiki. You can check on coverage, route options etc there, and use that to help decide which one to use.

Comment: I was trying OpenRouteService earlier and it was very unresponsive, but it does indeed seem to be working now... but it's really slow... took a couple of minutes to finish the initial load just now.

Comment: ([Why shouldn't we use the word 'here' in a textlink](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-the-word-here-in-a-textlink) ... applies to "this" too)

Comment: I believe ORS is a volunteer run system, so while it normally works it can always have an off-day!